# Must a jew-by-choice who is a firstborn observe the fast of the firstborn

Tags: halacha, passover, fast-days, conversion-to-judaism, bechor-firstborn

I'm interested in the question of whether a ger who is firstborn (of both parents, say, to keep things simple) must follow the rules for Ta'anit B'khorot. There are some remarks on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_of_the_Firstborn#Breaking_the_fast), but they're quite terse and I'd be interested to hear more about the background and opinions of poskim on this issue.

Obviously, this is just an academic question and one should CYLOR if it applies directly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[The Nitei Gavriel Pesach 2 Chapter 43:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46448&st=&pgnum=227) brings in the name of the Shevet Halevi that since a convert is as if he is newly born there is a question whether he is still considered a Bechor. Therefore the Nitei Gavriel concludes that it is best that he should either make a Siyum or be part of a Seudas Mitzva.

Comment: It's the Shevet HaLevi (8:117), not Beis HaLevi. And the Shevet Halevi doesn't mention a siyum, rather he says that one should just snack but refrain from eating a full meal (יתענה מסעודה)

Comment: Moreover, the Shevet HaLevi's argument is predicated on the non-Jew being a biological first born, since were he in Egypt as a non-Jew he would have been killed, but had he converted back then, he would have been saved. But if the non-Jew were not a biological first born, then he never would have been subjected to the threat of death, so what sense would there be to fast?

Comment: If you read the Nitei Gavriel it is clearly talking about a convert who was a firstborn. Everyone would agree if the convert is not a firstborn there is no need for him to fast.

Comment: @GershonGold the only argument I could think of for this, though I found no support in the poskim, is that a ger is not considered related to his parents halachically and thus might be considered a "firstborn".

Answer (score 11):

R Eliezer Dunner of Bene Brak told me, a ger firstborn, to fast. (The siyumim had already concluded.)

Answer (score 6):

Because of the safek discussed by the Shevet HaLevi, Rav Elyashiv shlit"a recommends "that these bechorim participate in a seudas mitzvah." (http://torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5758/pesach.html; Harav Y.S. Elyashiv - Seder ha-Aruch, vol. 3, pg. 44).

Comment: Fred, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for this source! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.